# How do assembly languages depend on operating systems?

Tags: assembly, operating-system

As An assembly language implements a symbolic representation of CPU instructions which are independent on OSes while assemblers are always running under some OS, I was wondering how assembly languages depend on operating systems? For example, will assembly languages be the same for the same CPU with different OSes? Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As others have pointed out, system calls and interrupts are different. I can think of another few differences.

The instruction set is the same across all OSes on a given processor, but the executable file format might not be. For example, on the x86, Windows uses the PE format, Linux uses ELF, and MacOS uses Mach-O. That means that assemblers on those platforms must produce their output in those formats, which is a difference.

Relatedly, the calling convention could also be different across different OSes. That probably only matters where you are writing assembly code that calls or is called by compiled-code routines, or perhaps where you are writing inline assembler in some compiled code. The calling convention governs which registers are used for what purposes during a function call, so different conventions require different use of registers by calling and called code. They also put constraints on the position of the stack pointer, and various other things. As it happens, calling conventions have historically been a rare example of consistency across OSes in many cases: i believe the Windows and UNIX calling conventions are the same on the x86 (and are all based on the venerable UNIX System V ABI specification), and are consistent across OSes on most other architectures. However, the conventions are now different between Windows and UNIX on the x86_64.

In addition, there may be differences in the syntax used by the assembly language. Again on the x86, the Windows and Linux assemblers used to use different syntax, with the Windows assembler using a syntax invented by Intel, and the Linux assembler (really, the GNU assembler) using a traditional UNIX syntax invented by AT&T. These syntaxes describe the same instruction set, but are written differently. Nowadays, the GNU assembler can also understand the Intel syntax, so there is less of a difference.

Comment: I thought about adding a section on executable formats too, but AFAIK assemblers take care of that themselves without the programmer caring about the format used. Either way, great answer, +1

Comment: @delnan: Yes, you're right, the assembler will take care of the output format. Do the different formats introduce differences in the way you declare data sections on so on, or the lengths of symbols you can use? If not, then indeed, there are no user-visible differences.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. Symbol length *shouldn't* be an issue as long as they don't get insanely long (thousands of characters), and assemblers should be able to abstract section details away, but then again, I've never really written significant assembly code.

Comment: As far as I could tell, system calls and interrupts are not  part of an assembly language, but are rather implemented by the OS using assembly code. So, the fact that they are OS-specific does not mean that assembly itself is.

Answer (score 7):

The instructions available (and each instruction's semantics, of course) depends on the CPU, not on the OS - so in a way, you are right.

*But* for most tasks of interest (I/O for example), you have to talk to the OS (making system calls). Cross-platform abstractions over these things don't exist at that level (well, you *could* try to use `libc` for instance, but even then you need to know the calling convention used, which can differ between platforms, etc. - in the end, you'd have to put quite some work into building such an abstraction yourself, so AFAIK few of the few people who program in assembly bother to try), to do something not possible with the (OS-independent) CPU instructions, you have to know what OS you're programming for and how to tell that OS to do it.

This doesn't apply as heavily for inline assembly code in e.g. C code, as it is mostly used to make purely CPU-bound computations in a smarter/faster way than the compiler is expected to).

Comment: As for CPUs, Are CPU codes generally standardized then? If not, wouldn't code that work on a CPU largely not work on another?

Comment: @Pacerier Yes, there are only a couple of instruction sets which are implemented by almost all CPUs. For example, virtually any Intel or AMD CPU will support the x86 and x86-64 instructions.

Comment: So it's actually feasible to write a CPU-independent app that's also OS-independent?

Comment: @Pacerier Where did you get that from? As I wrote in the answer, many tasks, including some absolutely necessary to be called an "app", *are* OS-dependent. And while there are only a couple of CPU families, that's still more than one - machine code that works on your desktop computer won't run on your phone or tablet, and perhaps not even on a server farm.

Comment: Well but at least if we aren't too choosy, there's actually exists a small subset of commands that work on all CPUs and all OSes!

Comment: @Pacerier No, not on all CPUs. ARM CPUs are completely different beasts from x86 and so are MIPS CPUs (to name only three popular ones). Not only do these three families have no instructions in common, their instruction encoding is also completely different so binaries would be incompatible even if they shared instructions.

Comment: Ah, looks like it's mission impossible then.

Answer (score 4):

Assembly languages don't depend on an OS, but on the CPU's instruction set.

Only if you call API functions (like for example a Windows API function from inline assembler code in MSVC), you get an OS dependency.

Answer (score 3):

Assembly language has nothing to do with it, you can take your question (how xyz language depends on operating systems) and use C, pascal, ada, fortran, and a long list of other languages and ask the same question with the same answer, the language has nothing to do with it.  The system calls into the operating system using the calling convention for the operating system is what matters,  *IF* you are using the same language or a language with the same calling convention as the operating systems definition, that makes life easier but does not lock you into anything.  pretty much any language can be used as you likely well know, the standards C, C++, etc as well as the virtual or runtime interpreted, etc java, perl, python, shell script, javascript, etc.  They all seem to run on my computer at least.  Somewhere (language specific) is a shim that makes the system calls into the operating system in a manner defined by the operating system.  Asm makes life easy for some of those languages since you are bound by no rules you can use asm to make that shim between the language calling convention and the operating system call desired.  Likewise using asm makes it easy to interface to any calling convention be it language defined or operating system defined.

Also as already answered assembly language is independent of the operating system or any other software running on the cpu.  it is tied directly to the cpu's instruction set.  Now there is the machine code, the actually bits executed by the processor, those do not change, but the ascii files used to represent those instructions, that language can change but not because of the cpu nor the operating system, those differences have to do with the toolchain.  For example x86 att syntax vs intel syntax.  Same instruction set, same machine code, different assembly language.  and if you look around enough tasm, masm, etc there are many assemblers for x86 and each have their own directives and other toolchain specific nuances.

Answer (score 2):

The assembly language should be the same; as you point out, the instruction set depends only on the CPU and its architectural design. Where you start getting into trouble with different OSs, I believe, is when you start invoking e.g. interrupts (typically for I/O) which can definitely mean programs written for e.g. MSDOS won't work on e.g. Solaris (maybe a bad example).

Answer (score 2):

An assembler translates mnemonics (e.g. `jump`, `mov`, `add`, etc.) from an assembly language into machine instructions. Machine instructions are entirely dependent on the hardware (they represent the hardware/CPU instruction set).

If you ever wanted to come up with an assembly language, you would need to also design/write an assembler that would do the mapping to machine instructions. In that sense if you target a given machine architecture, the assembler should produce machine specific code, not OS specific code. However, the *assembler implementation* may (and generally *is*) OS-specific, because of the output program it produces (a Unix executable is not the same as a Windows executable, even though the underlying machine instruction set is x86, for example).

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_assemblers) what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

The OS doesn't matter. You could have the same assembler on different OSes, you can use different compilers on the same OS, hey, you can even cross compile, targeting different systems.

Answer (score -3):

I think LINKER is responsible for making OS specific executable file format adding dynamic link liabaries (.dll) etc.  It stamps for specific OS format file to executable ones.

Comment: If you consider Windows vs. Linux, Windows `.obj` files are already a different format (COFF) from ELF `.o` object files used on GNU/Linux.  And would have different machine-code and metadata if you compiled the same C program for those OSes.  It's true that you need a linker specific for your OS and its file format, though.  (Linux and *BSD both use ELF object files, but are not binary compatible, so just using the same file format on the same ISA isn't sufficient.)