# Is "assembly language" different with or without an OS?

Tags: assembly, operating-system, bootloader

I am reading a book about x86/x86-64 assembly programming.
In that book almost all of the experiments are loaded by a "loader".
This makes me really confused since I never work with this kind of assembly code before.

I am wondering if the assembly generated from a `-S` or a `--emit-asm` compiler option is running in a "virtual environment", where the hardware is abstracted by the OS?

When I see an `eax`, `xmm0` or `esp` in an asm file which is output by a compiler,
do they mean real registers in my CPU? or just a conceptual object which will be interpreted by OS at run-time?

Comment: I guess `eax,esp`,etc. correspond to real 32 bit registers present in your processor!

Comment: You can find diferent notations even for x86/x86-64 assembly, you have the Intel syntax (ex.: mov eax,[ecx]), and the AT&T syntax (same ex.: movl (%ecx),%eax). But registers are the same, is the same architecture. If you take a look at ARM (or other) you will see different registers. And the instruction set is the same across all OS's on a given processor.

Comment: The machine code is the same, but the execution environment isn't. This includes what privilege level you are running at, what services you may invoke, how your code gets loaded, and so on.

Comment: You are looking at a friendly representation of bytes in a file.  That file needs to be loaded into memory before the processor can execute the program.  That is the job of the loader.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do assembly languages depend on operating systems?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859348/how-do-assembly-languages-depend-on-operating-systems)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am wondering if the assembly generated from a -S or a --emit-asm compiler option is running in a "virtual environment", where the hardware is abstracted by the OS?

For the most part, it's the same physical hardware. If you're running in a virtual machine environment (VMWare, HyperV) then it's naturally abstracted.

There are several cases where the OS does indeed abstract the hardware. Obsolete and unsupported instructions are sometimes emulated. Interaction with certain hardware peripherals is sometimes allowed by the OS via emulating INP/OUTP commands - those are normally prohibited for nonkernel code.

Certain commands don't work under an OS the way they would work on bare iron - for example, stack growth is implemented via guard pages, where memory access beyond the allowed area causes the OS to take control and grow the stack.

Bue when it comes to vanilla commands (e. g. `mov eax, esp`), it's executed on the physical hardware.

Answer (score -1):

These are the real registers and the assembly languages change with the computer architecture so as the registers